# Bootstrap navbar appearing on 2 lines in Safari on first load

Tags: html, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, safari, mobile-safari

This is the code I have for my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-nav btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-left previous_page" style="display:inline-block">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span>
      back
    </button>

    <div class="text-center" id="progress-bar" style="display:inline-block">
      <div data-page="0" class="counter active"></div>
      <div data-page="1" class="counter "></div>
      <div data-page="2" class="counter "></div>
      <div data-page="3" class="counter "></div>
      <div data-page="4" class="counter "></div>
     </div>

    <button type="button" class="navbar-nav btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right next_page disabled" style="margin-right:0px;display:inline-block">

      next
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

On Safari on iPhone 7, 8, X devices, when you FIRST load the page, the navbar appears on 2 different lines like so:

[image: Site view in Safari browser]

Then, when you refresh or reload it, it appears normal like so:

[image: Site view in Safari browser]

I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to get it to always appear normal, and am even more boggled by why a secondary page load corrects the issue.

Note, I added `display:inline-block` to all 3 navbar elements to try to correct this problem. It's done something... BEFORE I added it, when it was just Bootstrap native styling, on the Safari and iPhone 7, 8, X devices, even refreshing wouldn't help, and the navbar would stay split on 2 rows.

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I go through this i found this solution rather than giving it inline you can use bootstrap class `checkbox-inline` which will make the center div inline and give navbar `text-center` class. Use `pull-left` and `pull-right` instead navbar-left and navbar-right. Hope it will help you :)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top text-center" style="background: red;">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-nav btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-left previous_page">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span>
  back

    </button>
    <div class="text-center checkbox-inline" id="progress-bar">
        <div data-page="0" class="counter active"></div>
        <div data-page="1" class="counter "></div>
        <div data-page="2" class="counter "></div>
        <div data-page="3" class="counter "></div>
        <div data-page="4" class="counter "></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-nav btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-right next_page disabled">
  next

        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span>
    </button>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! So to solve my exact problem `checkbox-inline` is not needed, only the `pull-left` and `pull-right`. I also looked at the source code to figure out why, for whatever reason, Bootstrap 3.3.4, `navbar-left` and `navbar-right` are scoped to NOT work until tablet size! This really makes no sense to me, but there you have it. Both classes just add a `float: left/right !important`. I still cannot figure out why when I had my original set-up, refreshing the page made it work, if you would care to comment on that, would still be interesting for me!

Comment: i would love to do that, actually i have windows pc, if possible we can share screens and resolve it :)

Comment: i don't have that ability, but I can put the old page up on a sandbox site and  you'll be able to clearly see the issue on your screen

Comment: sure, just ping me when you do it !

Comment: hmm... this is the staging. but unfortunately refreshing it doesn't fix it like it did before https://hidden-tundra-8656.herokuapp.com/place-order

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by fixing the height of the navbar. Try giving the navbar a fixed height: i.e

```
.container_navbar{ height: 60px; ... }
```

The fixed height works across all devices.

Hope this works for you

Best regards